# All redirects suddenly not working (404 Not Found)

Tags: redirection

I have no idea why this suddenly isn't working. Drupal 7, with the current Redirect module (7.x-1.0-rc1). The redirects are set as 301 Default. They are all now returning a 404 error instead of redirecting.

Deleting the redirect and creating it anew doesn't resolve the problem. I'm not sure what to do next. I haven't updated the core or any other modules lately. Help!! Any idea where I should look next?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What were the changes you made before it stopped working?

Comment: @Randell - No changes, just uploading, editing, and removing content to the site.

I have a development site, which I've made exactly identical to production -- same core and module versions, same files, same db data. Redirects work on the development site, but not on production.

I'm out of ideas... Copy dev to production?

Comment: I'd track those changes first if possible. Then if not, it's time to use the backup.